# HIbernate lazy-loading behaviour when fetching collections from Spring MVC @Controller

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions, lazy-loading

Let's say I have the following method in a Spring MVC `@Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list")
public ModelAndView renderView(@PathVariable("id") int id, @ModelAttribute("someForm") SomeForm someForm) {

    SomeEntity someEntity = someEntityService.findById(id);
    someForm.setEntity(someEntity);
    someForm.setLstFromEntity(
            new ArrayList<SomeSubEntity>(someEntity.getSomeSubEntities())
            );

    return new ModelAndView("someView", "someForm", someForm);
}
```

`someEntityService` is a `@Transactional` `@Service` and the collection I am fetching it is lazy-loaded so it makes sense to think that the fetching would fail cause of no session being active (I am not sure if this is true). Fetching works perfectly though.

However, I have another method annotated as `@RequestMapping(value = "/save")` that perfoms a save and calls `renderView()` to return the view to the client.
In this case, `someEntity.findById(id)` returns the entity but without firing any select to the database. All fields are populated but the collection (PersistentBag) is empty, so the entity is incomplete.

Several questions:

- Is the session really closed?
- Where is this someEntity coming from in the second case?
- Why is the collection being returned empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think that the reason of this question being unanswered is the lack of information. When I save a *new* instance of SomeSubEntity, I use two IDs to define two relations it has with another entities of the model.

```
new SomeSubEntity(foo1Id, foo2Id);
```

And the constructor of SomeSubEntity does something like:

```
public SomeSubEntity(Integer idFoo1, Integer idFoo2) {
    this.setFoo1(new Foo1(idFoo1));
    this.setFoo2(new Foo2(idFoo2));
}
```

The constructor of `Foo1`/`Foo2` sets the IDs specified and nothing else.

`foo1Id` and `foo2Id` match two IDs of two entities of `Foo1` and `Foo2` already persisted in the database and related to `SomeSubEntity` via foreign keys (and Hibernate mappings), so the transaction completes succesfully.

However, it seems that the entities of `Foo1` and `Foo2` that remain in the session are the same that were created (IDs only, no update from database), so when I get a property from them, default class values are returned instead of the real value from the database.

I solved it using managed entities from the DB instead of creating a new one with a matching ID:

```
public SomeSubEntity(Foo1 foo1, Foo2 foo2) {
    this.setFoo1(foo1);
    this.setFoo2(foo2);
}

new SomeSubEntity(
    foo1DAO.findById(idFoo1),
    foo2DAO.findById(idFoo2)
);
```

The drawback is that queries are (obviously) fired to the database.